# How to calculate run-time for a multi-threaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to test the performance (in terms of execution time) for my webcrawler but I am having trouble timing it due to multi-threading taking place.

**My main class:**

```
class WebCrawlerTest {
    //methods and variables etc
    WebCrawlerTest(List<String> websites){
    //
    }

    if(!started){
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32); //this is the value I'm tweaking
        started=true;
    }       
    for(String site : websites){
        executor.submit(webProcessor = new AllWebsiteProcessorTest(site, deepSearch));
    }                               
    executor.shutdown();
    //tried grabbing end time here with no luck
```

**AllWebsiteProcessorTest class:**

```
class AllWebsiteProcessorTest implements Runnable{
    //methods and var etc

    AllWebsiteProcessorTest(String site, boolean deepSearch) {
    }
    public void run() {         
        scanSingleWebsite(websites);
        for(String email:emails){
            System.out.print(email + ", ");
        }

private void scanSingleWebsite(String website){
    try {
        String url = website;
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        grabEmails(document.toString());
    }catch (Exception e) {}
```

With another class (with a `main` method), I create an instance of `WebCrawlerTest` and then pass in an array of websites. The crawler works fine but I can't seem to figure out how to time it.

I can get the start time (`System.getCurrentTime...();`), but the problem is the end time. I've tried adding the end time like this:

```
//another class 
public static void main(.....){
    long start = getCurrent....();
    WebCrawlerTest w = new WebCrawlerTest(listOfSites, true);
    long end = getCurrent....();
}
```

Which doesn't work. I also tried adding the `end` after `executor.shutdown()`, which again doesn't work (instantly triggered).  How do I grab the time for the **final completed thread**?

Comment: You can change you `Runnable` into `Callable` which return result is timestamp of completion, then aggregate this timestamps by `Future#get()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After shutting down your executors pool

```
executor.shutdown();
//tried grabbing end time here with no luck
```

You can simply

```
executor.awaitTermination(TimeUnit, value)
```

This call will block untill all tasks are completed. Take the time, subtract `T0` from it and voila, we have execution time.

`shutdown()` method just assures that no new tasks will be accepted into excution queue. Tasks already in the queue will be performed (`shutdownNow()` drops pending tasks). To wait for all currently running tasks to complete, you have to `awaitTermination()`.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, and thanks for the extra info! :-)! The `shutdownNow()` is another method which I will definitely need in the near future!